# Set value to 0 via pointer to char

Tags: c, pointers

I want to set the value of the (dereferenced) passed variable to `NULL` if it is a `const char *` and to `0` if it is a `double`, assuming that `NULL` is defined as `(void *)0` and `sizeof(const char *) == sizeof(double)`, is this code safe? is there a better approach to achieve the same?

If not, please, don't suggest to use `union`s, I am stuck with `void *` (building an interpreter) and I can not pass the type as parameter, I only need those 2 type (`const char *` and `double`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void set0(void *param)
{
    if (sizeof(const char *) == sizeof(double)) {
        *(const char **)param = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *str = "Hello";
    double num = 3.14;

    printf("%s\n", str);
    printf("%f\n", num);
    set0(&str);
    if (str != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    set0(&num);
    printf("%f\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The *right* thing to do is to remember which one it is. You know `sizeof(const char *) == sizeof(double)` isn't true on most 32-bit architectures?

Comment: How do you expect this to run on a 32-bit system, where (typically) a `double` will be twice as large as a pointer? You need more information.

Comment: @unwind: Notice the `if (sizeof(const char *) == sizeof(double))`

Comment: @AlterMann So on 32-bit systems it doesn't set it to 0 or NULL. So on 32-bit systems, it doesn't work because it doesn't do what it's supposed to.

Comment: Wouldn't `static_assert(sizeof(const char*) == sizeof(double), "Incompatible target machine");` be more efficient? (or can the compiler optimize the `if` to a compile-time thing in this scenario?)

Comment: @Michael, but `static_assert` is a C++ artifact, isn't it?

Comment: No, it's a C11 thing. But it also works in C++, at least with g++ 5.2.0.

Comment: @Michael, then yes, it is useful, but the question is, can I assume that this code sets `0` or `NULL` in a safer mode?

Comment: @AlterMann You're trying to write to a string literal location. It will trigger an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C11 you could simply do this:

```
#define set0(param) \
  if (sizeof(const char *) == sizeof(double)) \
  { param = _Generic((param), double: 0.0, const char*: NULL); }

...

set0(str);
set0(num);
```

or if you will (uglier macro, prettier call):

```
#define zero(param)                                     \
  (sizeof(const char *) == sizeof(double)               \
   ? _Generic((param), double: 0.0, const char*: NULL)  \
   : param) 

...

str = zero(str);
num = zero(num);
```

This also has the advantage of type safety, which your `void*` function lacks.

Otherwise, you would be out of luck. Pointer conversions from `double*` to `const char**` are not well-defined. The rules of pointer aliasing allow pointer conversions from `type*` to `const char*` but not to `const char**`.

In order to write this code with a function taking a `void*`, you would have to add an additional type information parameter.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I have no access to the object itself, variables are always passed as pointers `(void *)` to the interpreter, in other words, I can not use `_Generic` because at the moment to call `set0` they are pointers (not primitive types), an example: `if (get(this), set(this, format("%0*.0f", size(this), val(get(this)))), /* else */ set(this, 0))`, in the second `set` I don't know the type of `this`, time to redesign all, thank you anyway.

Comment: _The rules of pointer aliasing allow pointer conversions from type* to const char* but not to const char**._. But there is not such conversion, the passed element is a `const char *` dereferenced in `*(const char **)param = 0;`

Comment: @AlterMann Here `*(const char **)param` the _effective type_ of the object pointed at by param is `double`. You are essentially writing `(const char**)(void*)&double_obj` which is equivalent to  `(const char**)&double_obj`

Comment: You forget the dereference operator, `*(const char **)` results in a `const char *` , not in a `(const char**)&`, in fact `(const char **)&param = 0;` raises `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

Comment: Ok Lundin,I have spent several hours but I get your point: I am dereferencing an invalid cast (`double *` --> `const char **`), you mean the dereference is applied after the (invalid) conversion, isn't it?

Comment: @AlterMann Yes. The cast and the unary * operator have the same precedence, but right-to-left associativity, meaning that the cast happens before the de-reference.

Comment: Thank you Lundin, now I understand, and excuse me for being a little obtuse.

Answer (score 5):

In order for this to be safe even on platforms where `sizeof(double)` is the same as `sizeof(const char*)` one other condition must be in place: the way the system represents `double`s must interpret bits of a `NULL` pointer as `0.0`.

Although this is true for many platforms, because both `NULL` and `0.0` are represented as sequences of zero bytes of identical length, the standard by no means requires this to be true. Zero double may have a representation different from what it is in IEEE-754. Similarly, `NULL` pointer is not required to be represented as a zero (although the compiler must ensure that zero comparison of `NULL` pointer succeeds). Therefore, you end up with rather unportable code.

Comment: Exactly, you have to be sure about the floating point standard of the platform you are dealing with.

Comment: Thank you guys, then there is not a portable way without an extra parameter defining the type, isn't it?

Comment: @AlterMann Correct, the compiler needs to know the type.

Comment: Sorry for retract the acepted vote, but there was another problem, see Lundin's answer, anyway your answer is very useful.